# How do I change the default wwwroot in Windows Server 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis

I know it should be in the IIS MMC somewhere, but I'm not sure where. Anyone know where to change the default wwwroot folder?

Comment: Do you want to change where the default site points to on disk?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just right-click the default web in the list of websites in the IIS Manager. Go to the "Home Directory" tab and change the local path:

Normally it is the first item in the list. Its name on English Windows installations is "Default Web Site". The default web normally responds to port 80 requests for all http headers on all assigned IP addresses, even if they are not explicitly set (tab "Web Site", "Web site identification" button "Advanced...".

Comment: I'm not really sure which is the default; there are several. Should it be obvious?

Comment: Normally its name is "Default Web" and is the first in the list. The default web normally responds to "all" http headers, even if they are not explicitly set (tab "Web Site", "Web site identification" button "Advanced..." - there you should see an empty http header.

Comment: The "Default Web Site" is the one with IIS identifier #1.

Answer (score 2):

Right click the Default Site in IIS admin. Its called Home Directory.

Answer (score 0):

The **default** site is set to listen on port 80. The other answers showed how to change the home directory.